# Pass on a Tap to an UITextView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitouch

I was wondering how to pass on a tap on an UIView to an UITextView. This is my code so far:

```
- (void)foundTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

label.text = @"Touch detected";

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:aTextView];

[aTextView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
```

}

Now, this obviously does not work as touches and event are not defined. But how do I define them? I can't declare touches as 1 (won't work). I could initialise it like so:

```
UITouch *touches =[touches anyObject];
```

But then again, touches is still undeclared. And I have no idea of how to declare the event. This is usually easy if you use the `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}` method, but I want to pass on the tap not the touches. Any help would be very much appreciated.

---

Edit:

I rewrote the method, but I still can't pass on the tap to the UITextView. I now need to double tap in order to edit it, i.e. the first tap for bringing the aTextView upfront and the second tap will then edit the UITextView (as it is in front and thus receives all the touches swipes etc.):

```
 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.x - currentPosition.x); // will always be positive
    CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.y - currentPosition.y); // will always be positive


    if (deltaY == 0 && deltaX == 0) {

        label.text = @"Touch"; [self performSelector:@selector(eraseText) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:aTextView];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:doneEdit];

        [aTextView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this previous SO question [iPhone: Detecting Tap in MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275731/iphone-detecting-tap-in-mkmapview) helps you.

Comment: Hmm... not really, unless it shows that it is generally difficult what I try to achieve. I thought it was quite a basic problem, didn't realise that it was so problematic. Thanks for posting the link!

Comment: Go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446831/getting-the-uitouch-objects-for-a-uigesturerecognizer also

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is what I was looking for (at least I can't see how it relates to my question, but that may be due to me not understanding the issue correctly).